OpenSearch not starting - [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];
After indexing some documents, my OpenSearch is not starting. In the opensearch.log file, I get this error:
org.opensearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: index [.opensearch-observability] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];
    at org.opensearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.indicesBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:243) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.indexBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:221) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.action.admin.indices.create.TransportCreateIndexAction.checkBlock(TransportCreateIndexAction.java:95) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.action.admin.indices.create.TransportCreateIndexAction.checkBlock(TransportCreateIndexAction.java:56) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.action.support.clustermanager.TransportClusterManagerNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.doStart(TransportClusterManagerNodeAction.java:237) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.action.support.clustermanager.TransportClusterManagerNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onNewClusterState(TransportClusterManagerNodeAction.java:336) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onNewClusterState(ClusterStateObserver.java:380) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.clusterChanged(ClusterStateObserver.java:230) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.callClusterStateListener(ClusterApplierService.java:625) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.callClusterStateListeners(ClusterApplierService.java:613) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.applyChanges(ClusterApplierService.java:577) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService.runTask(ClusterApplierService.java:484) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$UpdateTask.run(ClusterApplierService.java:186) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:849) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedOpenSearchThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedOpenSearchThreadPoolExecutor.java:282) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.opensearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedOpenSearchThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedOpenSearchThreadPoolExecutor.java:245) ~[opensearch-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]

I have emptied my disk a bit (Win11 system) and I now have 64GB free, but the error won't go away.
I've found some related ElasticSearch questions, but I don't think I can use any of the solutions, given that I can't even start OpenSearch:
Elasticsearch read_only_allow_delete auto setting
BTW, my free disk storage space is at 16%. For ElasticSearch they say that 15% is required to be free, in my provided link.
Any ideas on what can be done?
Update :
I have freed up more space and my disk has now 20% free space. Nothing changes with OpenSearch...
Update #2 :
I have freed up more space and my disk has now 25% free space. Nothing changes with OpenSearch...
Update #3 :
I have moved the OpenSearch folder to an external disk with 75% free space. Nothing changes with OpenSearch... This is insane! What is wrong with it?
Update #4 :
The full logs:
https://mega.nz/file/tMsDRDjQ#AxDAfuv_0A5wj1qdUmLhbPyzQksqLCdnfJNusxba3EQ

Can you share the following API call results? GET _cat/allocation?v&h=host,node,disk.indices,disk.used,disk.avail,disk.total
and
GET .opensearch-observability/_settings?include_defaults&filter_path=**.index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete

@MusabDogan Since OpenSearch does not run, how can I do that? Is there another way to do that?

Sorry, I read your message again and just understand your issue. The log you shared can't cause stopping Opensearch service. Can restart the service and share the full logs of opensearch.

@MusabDogan I have updated the question with the full logs (see update #4). Indeed, there is an extra error: Failure No shard available for [org.opensearch.action.get.MultiGetShardRequest@27795f5b] retrieving configuration for [INTERNALUSERS, ACTIONGROUPS, CONFIG, ROLES, ROLESMAPPING, TENANTS, NODESDN, WHITELIST, ALLOWLIST, AUDIT] (index=.opendistro_security). No idea how did this happen...

I found this related post now : https://forum.opensearch.org/t/errors-at-opensearch-startup/16537/3   . I do have this in my config file: plugins.security.restapi.roles_enabled: ["all_access", "security_rest_api_access"] . And I have the security plugin enabled.

Thanks for sharing, it looks like disks are still full and .opendistro_security index read-only which causes shutdown. Kindly check your path.data in opensearch.yml and make sure there are enough space for the directory defined in path.data

@MusabDogan I don't have the path.data defined and it uses the default location. On that drive, there is 25% free space, and in my latest test it had 75% free space.
